# Undo directory move git bash

Tags: git, undo

I was trying to move a file from my Downloads folder to my repository and I ended up moving the Downloads folder.

this is the command i used

```
  mv ~/Downloads lesson_3_reflecton_prompts.txt
```

is there a way I can undo this?

Comment: `~/Downloads` is a folder while `lesson_3_reflecton_prompts.txt` is a file, right? If that's the case, are you sure you pasted the same command you used? In a Unix shell, when I `mv test-dir-a/ file-2.txt`, I just get the error `mv: cannot overwrite non-directory 'file-2.txt' with directory 'test-dir-a/'`. It would only work if the file were written before the directory.

Comment: that was directory, and i was in my repository directory in git  like this  
      ~/version-control/reflections (master)
             $ mv ~/Downloads lesson_3_reflecton_prompts.txt

Comment: Do you want to fix the changes to your repo, or to your system? In other words... is this really a question about git?

Comment: a fix to my system. the command left my download folder pathless, and I cannot manually add or edit path, maybe cause the system no longer recognizes the folder as a path. I think I have to create another download folder. I was hoping there was a git command to reverse the action

Comment: You've just renamed Downloads, so running the command backwards will fix it: `mv lesson_3_reflection_prompts.txt ~/Downloads`

Comment: I have been able to undo that, but still cant move the particular file I want