# Moving files from a directory to my current directory using git command

Tags: git, bash, file, version-control, git-bash

I am in need of the exact command to move a file from a directory to another. Lets say move a file  (file1.txt) in my Downloads directory to my current directory (version-control/newfolder) in git bash using git command?

I tried this command initially

```
mv ~/Downloads lesson_3_reflecton_prompts.txt
```

and it moved my Downloads directory to my version-control/newfolder direcotry and also changed the path of the Downloads directory.

I tried this other commad

```
mv Downloads/file1.txt file1.txt
```

and I got this error

```
mv: cannot stat 'Downloads/file1.txt': No such file or directory
```

I know there is a code to do this, I need it, and I have been searching for it.

Help

Comment: And what happened when you tried it? Did you get any error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo directory move git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329352/undo-directory-move-git-bash)

Comment: I got this error mv: cannot stat 'Downloads/file1.txt': No such file or directory

Comment: I have been able to undo that, but still cant move the particular file I want to the directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below commands to move `file1.txt` from `Downloads` directory to your git repo:

```
mv ~/Downloads/file1.txt file1.txt
```

And if you want to commit the `file1.txt` into your git repo, you can use the commands:

```
git add file1.txt
git commit -m 'add a file'
```